# Performance Issues with Matrix

Tags: matrix

Has there been any other updates to the performance issues?

I am running a site which has over 100 matrix rows per entry (with 4 columns per row) and saving times are abysmal (can be over 120 seconds).

I understand P&T is working full tilt on Craft, I just wish there was some love shown to EE Matrix :(

Similar and unanswered questions:

- [Long open/save for entries with 10-column Matrix fields](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/long-open-save-for-entries-with-10-column-matrix-fields/27109#27109)
- [Matrix is killing my load times - How can I speed it up](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17531/matrix-is-killing-my-load-times-how-can-i-speed-it-up)
- [Cause of Massive Performance Issues after EE Upgrade 2.5.2 to 2.7.2?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17267/cause-of-massive-performance-issues-after-ee-upgrade-2-5-2-to-2-7-2)

Any help would be welcomed :)

```
My specs

matrix 2.6.1
ExpressionEngine 2.9.2 Build 20141004
jQuery  1.7.2
MySQL   5.6.21-log
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0

PHP 5.6.3
register_globals    off
safe_mode   off
open_basedir    
max_execution_time  300
upload_max_filesize 50M
max_input_time  900
memory_limit    128M
session_save_path   writable
```

Comment: There's no nice way of saying this without sounding arrogant, so I apologise... but if your entries have 100+ matrix rows each you're doing it wrong in my opinion. Consider splitting those rows into separate channel entries and using relationships or shared categories instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as James commented above, this is not the best use of matrix.
When the website was planned and developed, there was no set idea of how many galleries would be needed per artist entry.  A rough estimate was 50, so in testing the performance was acceptable when using Matrix and Assets.

When the number of galleries per artist entry ballooned to the 150+, that is when performance really started hurting.  It worked, but not well.

I ended up building a system similar to what James suggested: I build a separate channel to hold the galleries and used relationships to tie them to the artist entry.

Re-entering the images and categories for each gallery was out of the question, so I build a system to export the current galleries with needed info into a large xml template file and used the handy DataGrab add-on to bring the galleries back in as individual entries with all needed data intact.  I also looked at solspace Importer, but I was unable to import multiple images into an assets field.